# Need help in optimize Android Fragment code

Tags: android, webview, fragment

Is there any way to reduce the code ?

As you can see below I try to load a webview with domain.com/?id=1 and id?=2 and so on and 
I have many **public static class DEMO*** how can I optimize it?

```
public class WebFragment extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_stack);
}

public static class DEMO1 extends Fragment {

    /** The Fragment's UI **/
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);

        WebView engine = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.web_engine);
        engine.loadUrl("http://domain.com/?id=1");
        }
        return v;
    }
}

public static class DEMO2 extends Fragment {

    /** The Fragment's UI **/
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);

        WebView engine = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.web_engine);
        engine.loadUrl("http://domain.com/?id=2");
        }
        return v;
    }
}

public static class DEMO3 extends Fragment {

    [... and so on ...]
```

Comment: Please sure your layout file also

Answer (score 1):

Pass the URL of the webview in the constructor ...

```
public static class Demo extends Fragment {
private String mUrl;
public Demo(String url) {
    this.mUrl = url;
}
/** The Fragment's UI **/
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);

    WebView engine = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.web_engine);
    engine.loadUrl(mUrl);
    }
    return v;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I kind of like the solution that is being given in the ApiDemos. I'll just copy over the relevant bits 'n pieces:

```
public static class CountingFragment extends Fragment {
    int mNum;

    /**
     * Create a new instance of CountingFragment, providing "num"
     * as an argument.
     */
    static CountingFragment newInstance(int num) {
        CountingFragment f = new CountingFragment();

        // Supply num input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("num", num);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    /**
     * When creating, retrieve this instance's number from its arguments.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;
    }

    ...
}
```

Source: [FragmentStack.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentStack.html)

You basically supply the variable as an argument when instantiating the fragment and retrieve it in onCreate. The same code is being illustrated in the [fragments fundamentals documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html), which might be worth a read.